# drag and drop in vuejs using an icon

Tags: html, css, typescript, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I am working on drag and drop feature in my vue.js,here is my parent component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
import AddCourseCard from './AddCourseCard.vue'
import CoursesCard from './CourseCard.vue'
import { OfferService } from '../../service/index'
import { GroupState } from '../../composition/groups'
import { IProduct } from '@/models/Products'

const JoinGroupModal = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/common/modal/JoinGroupModal.vue')
)

const products = ref(Array<IProduct>())
const pageNo = ref(1)
const limit = 10
const loading = ref(false)
const isGroupAdmin = ref(GroupState.state.isGroupAdmin)
const dragData = ref(null)
const draggedIndex = ref(null)
const dropTargetIndex = ref(null)
const canMove = ref(false)
const showJoinGroupModal = ref(false)
const isDataLoaded = ref(false)
const reachedEnd = ref(false)
const dragOptions = ref({
  group: 'cards',
  animation: 200,
})

const dummyData = ref([
  {
    title: 'Card 1',
    text: 'Some quick example text for Card 1',
    imageSrc: 'https://picsum.photos/1600/1176/?image=25',
  },
  {
    title: 'Card 2',
    text: 'Some quick example text for Card 2',
    imageSrc: 'https://picsum.photos/1600/1176/?image=26',
  },
  // Add more dummy data items as needed
])

const fetchProductsData = async () => {
  if (isGroupAdmin.value || GroupState.state.role === null)
    await fetchDataFromAPIForGroup()
  else await fetchDataFromAPI()
  isDataLoaded.value = true
}

const fetchDataFromAPI = async () => {
  if (loading.value) return // Prevent multiple requests while loading

  loading.value = true
  try {
    const response = await OfferService.getOfferProductForUser({
      pageNo: pageNo.value,
      limit: limit,
    })

    // Append the new data to the existing products array
    products.value = response
    console.log(products)

    // Increment the pageNo for the next request
    pageNo.value++
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data from API:', error)
  } finally {
    loading.value = false
  }
}

const fetchDataFromAPIForGroup = async () => {
  if (loading.value) return // Prevent multiple requests while loading

  loading.value = true
  try {
    const response = await OfferService.getOfferProductForGroup({
      pageNo: pageNo.value,
      limit: limit,
    })

    // Append the new data to the existing products array
    products.value = response
    console.log(products)

    // Increment the pageNo for the next request
    pageNo.value++
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data from API:', error)
  } finally {
    loading.value = false
  }
}

const handleDragStart = index => {
  console.log('START')
  draggedIndex.value = index
}

const handleDragOverCard = index => {
  dropTargetIndex.value = index
  // console.log(draggedIndex.value)
  //await OfferService.moveProduct(firstProductId, secondProductId, 'between')
}

const handleDragOverContainer = event => {
  // Prevent the default behavior, which is to not allow dropping
  event.preventDefault()
}

const handleDrop = async () => {
  console.log(draggedIndex.value)
  console.log(dropTargetIndex.value)
  if (draggedIndex.value !== null && dropTargetIndex.value !== null) {
    let type
    // Splice the dragged card out of the dummyData array
    const draggedCard = products.value.splice(draggedIndex.value, 1)[0]

    // Insert the dragged card at the drop target index
    products.value.splice(dropTargetIndex.value, 0, draggedCard)
    console.log(draggedIndex.value)
    console.log(dropTargetIndex.value)

    console.log(products.value[dropTargetIndex.value])

    const previousProductId =
      dropTargetIndex.value - 1 >= 0
        ? products.value[dropTargetIndex.value - 1].id
        : null

    const movedProductId = products.value[dropTargetIndex.value].id

    const nextProductId =
      dropTargetIndex.value + 1 < products.value.length
        ? products.value[dropTargetIndex.value + 1].id
        : null

    console.log(previousProductId, movedProductId, nextProductId)

    // Reset the dragged and drop target indices

    await OfferService.moveProduct(
      previousProductId,
      movedProductId,
      nextProductId
    )
    draggedIndex.value = null
    dropTargetIndex.value = null
    canMove.value = false
    fetchProductsData()
  }
}

const handleDragEnd = () => {
  dragData.value = null
}

const toggleMove = () => {
  canMove.value = !canMove.value
}

const handleOfferCreated = () => {
  fetchProductsData()
}

const deleteCourse = () => {
  fetchProductsData()
}

onMounted(async () => {
  // Call the initial API request when the component is mounted
  console.log(GroupState.state.role)
  showJoinGroupModal.value = GroupState.state.role ? false : true
  console.log(showJoinGroupModal.value)
  fetchProductsData()
})
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="isDataLoaded" class="flex w-full justify-center">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div v-if="isGroupAdmin" class="card">
        <AddCourseCard @create-offer-message="handleOfferCreated" />
      </div>
      <div class="card" v-for="(element, index) in products" :key="index">
        <CoursesCard
          :title="element.title"
          :description="element.description"
          :imageSrc="element.posterImage"
          :productId="element.id"
          :index="index"
          @toggleMove="toggleMove"
          @deleteCourse="deleteCourse"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
/* .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
} */

.card-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(calc(33.33% - 10px), 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 1216px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-items: space-between; /* Center the items horizontally */
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 10px; /* Add margin to all cards */
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.card:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  margin-left: 0; /* Remove the left margin for the first card in each row */
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
    max-width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .card {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Now here is my CourseCard componenet:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, defineAsyncComponent, h, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import {
  DotsVerticalIcon,
  DeleteIcon,
  ArrowUpRightIcon,
  MoveIcon,
  Trash01Icon,
  DotsGridIcon,
} from '@gohighlevel/ghl-icons/24/outline'
import { OfferService } from '../../service/index'
import { GroupState } from '../../composition/groups'
import {
  renderIcon,
  UIDisplaySmSemibold,
  UIDropdown,
  UITextLgMedium,
  UITextMdNormal,
} from '@gohighlevel/ghl-ui'
import { COURSES_PLACEHOLDER } from '@/util/const'

const JoinGroupModal = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('./JoinGroupModal.vue')
)

const props = defineProps({
  imageSrc: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: undefined,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: undefined,
  },
  productId: {
    type: String,
    default: undefined,
  },
  index: {
    type: Number,
    default: undefined,
  },
})

const menuOpen = ref(false)
const isGroupAdmin = ref(GroupState.state.isGroupAdmin)
const moveMode = ref(false)
const emit = defineEmits(['toggleMove', 'deleteCourse'])
const isCardHovered = ref(false)
const coursePlaceholderImage = ref('../../assets/course-placeholder.svg')
const cardToMove = ref(false)
const showJoinGroupModal = ref(false)
const truncatedTitle = computed(() => {
  const maxLength = 30
  if (props.title && props.title.length > maxLength) {
    return props.title.slice(0, maxLength) + '...'
  }
  return props.title
})
const menuOptions = [
  {
    label: 'Delete',
    key: 'delete',
  },
  {
    label: 'Move',
    key: 'move',
  },
]

const options = [
  {
    label: 'Delete',
    key: 'Delete',
    icon() {
      return h(renderIcon(Trash01Icon), null, {})
    },
  },
]

const showMenu = () => {
  menuOpen.value = true
}

const hideMenu = () => {
  menuOpen.value = false
}

const clickMove = () => {
  cardToMove.value = true
}

const toggleMenu = () => {
  menuOpen.value = !menuOpen.value
  isCardHovered.value = !isCardHovered.value
  console.log(menuOpen.value)
}

const deleteCard = async () => {
  // Implement your delete card logic here
  // You might want to emit an event to the parent component
  // to handle the deletion action.
  await OfferService.deleteProductFromGroup(props.productId as string)
  emit('deleteCourse')
}

const toggleMove = () => {
  moveMode.value = true
  console.log(moveMode)
  emit('toggleMove')
}

const handleDragStart = event => {
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'dummy') // Set dummy data for drag-and-drop
}

const handleDragEnd = () => {
  // Handle drag end if needed
}

const openProductPageInNewWindow = () => {
  if (GroupState.state.role === null) {
    showJoinGroupModal.value = GroupState.state.role ? false : true
    console.log(showJoinGroupModal.value)
    return
  }

  // Construct the URL by appending the productId to the current route's base URL
  const baseUrl = window.location.origin
  const productUrl = `${baseUrl}/courses/products/${props.productId}`
  const queryParam = 'source=communities'
  const finalUrl = `${productUrl}?${queryParam}`

  // Open the URL in the same browser tab
  window.location.href = finalUrl

  // Open the URL in a new browser window/tab
}

const hideCourseSettings = () => {
  if (menuOpen.value === false) {
    isCardHovered.value = false
  }

  console.log('hide called', isCardHovered.value, menuOpen.value)
}

const closeMenu = () => {
  menuOpen.value = false
}

onMounted(async () => {
  // Call the initial API request when the component is mounted
  document.addEventListener('click', closeMenu)
})
</script>
/* .rounded-card { display: flex; border-radius: 16px; overflow: hidden;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); height: 420px; width: 384px; } */
<template>
  <div
    class="border-1 flex h-[420px] w-[384px] overflow-hidden rounded-xl border-solid border-gray-300 bg-white hover:shadow-lg"
    :class="{ 'move-mode': moveMode, 'border-blue': cardToMove }"
    @mouseover="isCardHovered = true"
    @mouseout="hideCourseSettings"
    @click="openProductPageInNewWindow"
    :draggable="false"
  >
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="image-container">
        <!-- <div
          id="post-action-dropdown-trigger"
          class="showDiv ml-2 mt-2.5 flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-full hover:bg-gray-100"
        >
          <MoveIcon class="hideDiv h-6 w-6 text-gray-600" />
        </div> -->

        <div
          v-if="isGroupAdmin"
          class="ellipsis-menu flex w-full flex-row justify-between"
        >
          <div
            id="post-action-dropdown-trigger"
            class="flex gap-[1px] px-8 py-3"
            :class="{ hidden: !isCardHovered }"
            @click.stop="clickMove"
          >
            <MoveIcon class="h-4 text-gray-600" />
          </div>
          <div
            id="post-action-dropdown-trigger"
            class="flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-gray-100"
            @click.stop="toggleMenu"
            :class="{ hidden: !isCardHovered }"
          >
            <DotsVerticalIcon class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-600" />
          </div>
          <!-- Display the menu when 'menuOpen' is true -->
          <ul class="menu" v-if="menuOpen">
            <li @click.stop="deleteCard">
              <div class="delete-icon-container">
                <Trash01Icon class="text-black-500 h-4 w-4" />
                <span>Delete</span>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li @click.stop="toggleMove">
              <div class="delete-icon-container">
                <MoveIcon class="text-black-500 h-4 w-4" />
                <span>Move</span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <img
          :style="{ 'object-fit': imageSrc ? 'cover' : 'contain' }"
          :src="imageSrc || COURSES_PLACEHOLDER"
          alt="Card Image"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="px-6 py-4">
        <div class="title-arrow-container">
          <div class="flex w-full justify-between">
            <UITextLgMedium
              class="title-text"
              style="
                overflow: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
              "
            >
              {{ truncatedTitle }}
            </UITextLgMedium>
            <!-- <ArrowUpRightIcon
              class="text-black-500"
              style="
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-top: 3px;
                height: 24px;
                width: 24px;
              "
              @click="openProductPageInNewWindow"
            /> -->
          </div>

          <UITextMdNormal class="pt-2 font-normal text-gray-600">{{
            description
          }}</UITextMdNormal>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <JoinGroupModal
    :show="showJoinGroupModal"
    @update:show="showJoinGroupModal = false"
  />
</template>

<style scoped>
/* .rounded-card {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 420px;
  width: 384px;
} */
.content-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.image-container {
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* height: 240px; */
}

.title-arrow-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Change flex direction to column */
  align-items: flex-start; /* Align items to the start of the container */
  width: 100%;
}

.ellipsis-menu {
  position: absolute; /* Position the ellipsis-menu absolutely within the image-container */
  top: 10px; /* Adjust the top position to position it at the top of the image */
  right: 10px; /* Adjust the right position to position it at the right of the image */
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1; /* Ensure the icon is above the image */
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Initially hide the menu */
  list-style: none;
}
.menu li {
  width: 165;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu.show {
  display: block;
}
/* Show the menu when 'menuOpen' is true */
.delete-icon-container {
  display: flex; /* Use flexbox to place items side by side */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /* Vertically center items */
}
.delete-icon-container span {
  margin-left: 8px; /* Add some spacing between the icon and text */
}

.rounded-card.move-mode {
  border-color: blue; /* Add an outline when in move mode */
  cursor: move; /* Change cursor to indicate that it can be dragged */
}
.visible {
  display: block !important;
}

.move-icon-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0; /* Initially, make the move icon invisible */
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out; /* Add a smooth fade-in effect */
}

.rounded-card:hover .move-icon-container {
  opacity: 1; /* Make the move icon visible on hover */
}

.rounded-card.move-mode {
  border-color: blue;
  cursor: move;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
  padding-inline-end: 20px !important;
}

.hideDiv {
  display: none;
}

.rounded-card:hover .hideDiv {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.title-text {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #000; /* Specify the desired text color here */
}

.n-popover-shared {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
}

.border-blue {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
</style>
```

Now I am able to drag and drop items by holding on to cards,I want my drag and drop by holding on to `MoveIcon` in `CourseCard` component.

I tried adding draggable to  in MoveIcon but its not working,When i press and hold MoveIcon I am not able to drag it.

How to add it in `MoveIcon`? Please help here.